# How to render pages in nodejs with Router

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

how I can render my "firstsolution.ejs" page?
I have  "server.js", "routes" folder which contain "firstsolution.ejs" and "views" folder which contain "solutions" folder and solutions folder contain "solution1.ejs"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODJjC.png)

server.js code is:

```
   const fisrtsolution = require("./routes/firstsolution");
```

firstsolution.ejs code is:

```
    const express = require("express")

    const router = express.Router();


    router.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.render("./solutions/solution1");
     });

     module.exports = router;
```

but when I try to enter "http://localhost:3000/firstsolution" I see "Cannot GET /firstsolution"

Comment: check again your question and code

Comment: `Ejs` files are basically kept on `views` folder not in `routes` folder

Comment: Yes you are right, in question I wrote "firstsolution.EJS", but in VB I wrote correctly "firstsolution.js"

Comment: It says that it cannot get `/first solution`, so it's not a view problem, but a router problem... Can you share the server.js please, specially where you use the `const fisrtsolution = require("./routes/firstsolution");`

Comment: const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require('dotenv/config');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");


//  IMPORT ROUTES
const fisrtsolution = require("./routes/firstsolution");


mongoose.connect(
  process.env.DB_CONNECTION,{ useUnifiedTopology: true,useNewUrlParser: true  },
  () => console.log("connected to DB")
);
const port = 3000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`server  ${port}`))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to include the route in the app :

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require('dotenv/config');
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs"); // IMPORT ROUTES

const firstsolution = require("./routes/firstsolution"); 
app.use('/firstsolution', firstsolution);    // <--------- here

mongoose.connect( process.env.DB_CONNECTION,{ useUnifiedTopology: true,useNewUrlParser: true }, () => console.log("connected to DB") ); 
const port = 3000; 
app.listen(port, () => console.log(server ${port}))
```

Comment: I added as you say, but same problem again

Comment: @VardanHambardzumyan ok, normal, i didn't prefix the import of the route, take a loot again please

Comment: Inside the router file you specify '/' route, so in the server.js js, you have to include it by prefixin `/firstsolution`

Comment: like this? 
app.use("/fisrtsolution", fisrtsolution);

again says: "Cannot GET /firstsolution"
:\

Comment: @VardanHambardzumyan in the code you copy paste there is a typo error maybe : `const fisrtsolution `, but it should be something else

Comment: Oh my .... so stupid mistake...thanks Benard for your time :)))

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I hope my code will help you.

server.js code is:

```
app.use(require('./routes/firstsolution'));
```

firstsolution.ejs code is:

```
const express = require("express")

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("solutions/solution1");
});

module.exports = router;
```